# Applying an angular filter to a formly field

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

Is there an ability to set angular filters to formly fields? I've tried adding a "filter: 'uppercase'" to the templateOptions object, but to no avail, the input field remains lowercase.

And, if so, is adding parameters just as simple as "'myfilter:param1:param2'"?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could do it, but to make it work like that, you would need to make it an HTML template.

The easiest way would be to create a service and just set flags in the templateOptions that would determine if those functions get called and then return the values from expressionProperties that check the flags values.

For instance:

```
{
   key: 'Upper',
   templateOptions: {
       label: 'Name to Upper',
       upper: true
   }
},
expressionProperties: {
   'templateOptions.upper': function($viewValue, $modelValue, $scope) {
       if($scope.to.upper) $viewValue = ....//CALL UPPER CASE FUNCTION
       return $viewValue;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if this is a one time thing, you could simply do `$viewValue = $viewValue.toUpperCase();`

Comment: Wouldn't in this case create a custom filter? What if I want a prebuilt filter, like `date`?